# Append and element to an <a></a> if it has an specific anchor with jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with bootstrap using tabs. I am doing a nested tab which now supports many levels of tabs, but I want to append and icon `<i></i>` to all the nav list corresponding to the `tab-pane` how has a tab-group inside it. Following I explain better.

**Here is a basic example of what I have, the solution should work for many levels as possible:**

```
<div class="tab-group">
    <!-- Tab Links -->
    <ul class="nl-nav">
        <li><a href="#001" data-toggle="pill">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#002" data-toggle="pill">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#003" data-toggle="pill">link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <!-- Tab Content -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="001">Nothing</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="002">Nothing</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="003">
                

                <!-- NESTED TAB -->
                <div class="tab-group">
                    <!-- Tab Links -->
                    <ul class="nl-nav">
                        <li><a href="#004" data-toggle="pill">link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#005" data-toggle="pill">link 2</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Tab Content -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="004">Nothing</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="005">Nothing</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END NESTED TAB -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The idea**

As you can see in the first `.tab-group .tab-content > .tab-pane` you can find that `id="003"` has an other `.tab-group` inside.

Now in the first `.tab-group .nl-nav` I have to find which `<li>` element has the link `a` with the anchor `#003` and append a `<i></i>` to that link:

Example:

```
<ul class="nl-nav">
    <li><a href="#001" data-toggle="pill">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#002" data-toggle="pill">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#003" data-toggle="pill">link 3<i></i></a></li> <!-- Appended -->
</ul>
```

I have to repeat or do the same to all the `.nl-nav > .li` that can be found inside the tab-groups of the nested tabs corresponding to their own `.tab-content .tab-pane` contents

Comment: "but I want to append and icon <i></i>..." do you mean append an icon?  If so, the `<i>` tag is used for _italicising_ text...

Comment: What JavaScript/jQuery have you tried?

Comment: Why not generate the html correctly in the first place?

Comment: @Pineda yes you right but I am using that html element as a holder for the icon, the code for the icon is made up directly in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```js
$('.nl-nav a').filter(function() {
  return $(this.hash).find('.tab-group').length;
}).append('<i class="icon-class">')
```

```css
.icon-class:after {
  content: '... ICON';
  color: red;
}
.tab-content{
   padding-left:80px
}
.tab-pane .tab-group{
  margin-left:50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-group">
  <!-- Tab Links -->
  <ul class="nl-nav">
    <li><a href="#001" data-toggle="pill">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#002" data-toggle="pill">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#003" data-toggle="pill">link 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab Content -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="001">Nothing</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="002">Nothing</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="003">

      <!-- NESTED TAB -->
      <div class="tab-group">
      Nested tabs
        <!-- Tab Links -->
        <ul class="nl-nav">
          <li><a href="#004" data-toggle="pill">link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#005" data-toggle="pill">link 2</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab Content -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane" id="004">Nothing</div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="005">
            <!-- NESTED TAB -->
            <div class="tab-group">
            Nested tabs
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>


      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for being helpful, it solved the problem like a charm and with the less code possible. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you can select each `ul` and loop through them.
It could look like this:

```
var nlnavs = $("ul[class=nl-nav]");
for(var i = 0; i < nlnavs.length; i++){
  var childs = $(nlnavs[i]).children();
  for (var j = 0; j < childs.length; j++){
   $(childs[j]).append("<i>YOUR ICON</i>");
  }
}
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fxhyrre/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not add the icon just for those who has a tab-pane related with content